# Cannot find module @angular\cli\bin\ng

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I'm getting into trouble with anngular-cli installation because it doesn't recognize the ng command in my git bash but it works in my cmd on Windows 7.

I looked for some issues on the web but I didn't really find a solution.

Here, the error :

```
   ng -v
   module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

   Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program 
   Files\Git\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

This error happened the first time I used ng after installing Node and angular-cli globally.

I didn't get this error when I was working on my laptop on Windows 10.

Comment: Running this
`npm install -g @angular/cli` in root directory (for ex. in c:\\) removed this error for me.

Answer (score 54):

Problem:

> Error: Cannot find module
>   '..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng' angularJs

Solution:

1. uninstall angular cli if you have already installed it

   ```
   npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
   ```
2. Delete the C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular folder if it still exists after the uninstall
3. reinstall angular-cli globally

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli
   ```

Comment: 2.5 I also had to delete `ng.ps1` located in the `C:\users\<userid>\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder.

Comment: 3. or with a specific version if you aren't on latest e.g. `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.25`

Comment: removing npm and npm-cache folders from AppData helped me.and then doing the above helped me.

Comment: i ended up in this problem by running `npx npkill`

Answer (score 11):

First, uninstall the angular cli using

> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

Then delete the "NPM" and "Npm-cache" folder under "Roaming" folder.

Now again install the Angular cli using

> npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: This answer works for me, I has to delete npm folder under roaming

Answer (score 10):

In my case, i fixed it simply just by renaming my project folder.

before : "d/Gdrive/Sem 6 & 7/[project name]"
after : "d/Gdrive/Sem 67/[project name]"

So i guess u may not put special characters in your folder name.

Comment: Thanks, this is the right answer.  The build mechanism of Angular is really strange - I never came across such issue with React.

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me only by removing npm and npm-cache folders from AppData then running :

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Then running :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 4):

reinstall node_modules

1. git clean -dfx
2. npm i

*if persist, use yarn install first, then repeat above*

Comment: thx, solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a dependency was removed somewhere. I worked around this by:

For local angular-cli: `npm install @angular-devkit/core --save-dev`

For global angular-cli: `npm install -g @angular-devkit/core`

Edit: As discussed below, you should perhaps not use `--save-dev` here.

Answer (score 2):

Remove existing angular

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

and Install

`npm install -g @angular/cli --force`

Comment: This answer is already contained in the existing answers for solving the problem.

Comment: Reinstall without force maybe a got an error

Comment: @AdarshK thank you very much. All I needed to do was add a `--force` flag when installing Angular CLI. Your comment saved my mental health.

Answer (score 1):

The git bash is installed in `C:\Program Files\Git` where you never find the node_module folder that's why this error occurred

When you hit ng command from CMD it will look node_module folder in `C:\Users\uername\AppData\Roaming\npm\` - where npm install global dependency and eventually it finds node_modules folder.

Basically for windows try to run from cmd.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what it happened in my computer... I was able to run from CMD

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem is

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.js
npm ERR! dest C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.js' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<UserId>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-03T20_13_43_709Z-debug.log
```

Solution:

1. I use this comment of `npm` 5 line on the `shell`

   `$ npm ERR! File exists: C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng`
2. Delete the file `ng` and run:

```bash
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

And Done!

Comment: Just running the command in terminal helped: ```npm install -g @angular/cli```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

1. cd to the previous directory of node_modules in the error path

```
cd C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

2.working

```
npm config set prefix
```

3. 

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Anyway, it's resolved

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but running `npm install` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in Angular Console starting with release 11.
I was missing a locale cli. So

```
npm install @angular/cli
```

solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the package installation. Sometimes the installation might brake due to network issues. Also the access permission affects the installation.

So, try to install the package by **running command prompt (CMD) as Run as administrator**.

Follow the steps to resolve the issue.

**1.Run CMD as Run as administrator mode.**

**2.Uninstall angular cli.**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

**3.Remove npm package files from the appdata folder.**

Open Run option by pressing Windows + R key. Then type `%appdata%` and press OK.

Open the `npm` folder from the Roaming folder that you got in the explorer.

Delete `ng` and `ng.cmd` files from the `npm` folder if exists.

Open `node_modules` folder from there and delete `@angular` and `angular/cli` folder if exists.

**4.Reinstall the angular cli**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

If the environment variable path is properly set , please run ng in an angular project otherwise it will keep showing that error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

once you run npm uninstall -g @angular/cli, check if there is an error in the console, it is usually a message with red line says "err!", mine said that it was unable to delete a file , follow the path  of the file and delete manually ,then run npm uninstall -g @angular/cli and npm uninstall @angular/cli, when it goes successfully , run npm install -g @angular/cli , that should fix it.

Comment: Please check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Answer (score 0):

If most suggested and obvious solution below do not work

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
remove roaming -> npm
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Try to **upgrade Node.js** version. This **solved** the problem in my case after severl hours of investigation

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the node_modules folder (not the AppData one), the one in your project folder, and try reinstalling angular again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **MAC(Mackbook) pc** use brew command because we can not install angular-cli from npm command

```
brew install angular-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I spent a lot of time debugging the issue, trying to understand if it was specific to the NPM version or Angular before I realized that it could be the old fashion issue with **too long path when dealing with application development on Windows**.

---

So simply, instead of having my application path:

```
D:\...\Angular\...\...\application-name
```

I've changed it to a **shorter version**, like:

```
D:\application-name
```

and it worked, finally.