# I have installed Anuglar using cli , while checking angular version it is showing following error

Tags: node.js, angular

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\myalmala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng'

Comment: check this out -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726959/cannot-find-module-angular-cli-bin-ng

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall the angular cli if you have already installed it

> ```
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
> ```

2. Install the angular cli globally now.

> ```
> npm install -g @angular/cli
> ```

Comment: uninstalled angular and installed angular now it is showing this error : npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\myalmal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\myalmal\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng

Comment: seems like there is a problem with your node modules. try
`npm install`

Comment: i tried npm install - , now i got this error  :     'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Comment: can you try `npm install -g @vue/cli@latest
`

Comment: i tried it , i got these errors :   
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\
npm ERR! file C:\
npm ERR! path C:\
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! core-js-pure@3.17.2 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! spawn C:\ ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js-pure@3.17.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.