# Upgrade from Angular 9 to Angular 10 fails

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade an Angular project from Angular 9 to Angular 10 with the following command:

`ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10`

as per the instructions on the Angular web site.  But after downloading various packages, the upgrade fails with the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\userme\src\proj\ui\'C:\Users\userme\AppData\Local\Temp\angular-cli-packages-hbN45F\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng''
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

It looks as if it's trying to concatenate two absolute paths, resulting in an invalid path.  Is there any way I can work around this?

Comment: Does this answer [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804130)?

Comment: First try here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726959/cannot-find-module-angular-cli-bin-ng

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour  - thanks, that worked.